# How to start display specific child row in Expandable List View in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I want to start display specific position child from expandable list view in Android.
In List view, I am aware about:

```
    listview.smoothScrollToPosition(yourPosition);
    listview.setSelectionFromTop(n, 0);
```

These two methods to display specific row.

We can expand group in Expandable list view using expandablelistview.expandGroup(position) method.

I want to display specific child row from this expanded parent row.